# Compare strings in a SUMIF w/o spaces

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a question related to SUMIF formula if I can compare 2 strings in a SUMIF ignoring spaces.

My initial thought was that I can use trim, but it doesn't work in SUMIF range and further on in transposed in VBA.

```
"=SUMIF('[SDA decembrie.xlsx]Sheet1'!C2,RC[-29],'[SDA decembrie.xlsx]Sheet1'!C6)"
```

The main point is that I have 2 files: 1 that contains a column with some category names and another one that contains the same column with the same category names **except they have a space after the name**; 
EXAMPLE: File 1:"Category"
         File 2:"Category "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trim indeed doesn't work in the criteria range. The best solution probably would be to clean the data before processing it, but you could also try wildcards instead of trim:

```
''' "=SUMIF('[SDA decembrie.xlsx]Sheet1'!C2,"*"& RC[-29] &"*",'[SDA decembrie.xlsx]Sheet1'!C6) '''
```

This should match against any leading or trailing spaces, it of course won't work if there are spaces between 2 words in the criteria.

Comment: Hmm, something is wrong and I can't figure out what, it's a typing mistake, I think.

Comment: I've edited the previous post, hope it works like this.

Comment: "=SUMIF('[SDA martie.xlsx]com.ibm._jsp._excel_5F_synthese'!C2,RC[-29]," * "&" **'[SDA martie.xlsx]com.ibm._jsp._excel_5F_synthese'!C6"&"*")" ** the italic part is highlighted in gree, hmm.

Comment: For some reason I can't show the asterisks here... It's basically "asterisk" & "criteria" & "asterisk"

Comment: Then, shouldn't the wild card be positioned in the middle argument? Let's say we have =SUMIF(A:A,"*"B"*",C:C), is this right? Those quotation have always spooked me and they get on my nerves usually, haha.

Comment: That's correct. I'm sorry, I now see I put it around the wrong range, lol.

Comment: Still wrong, also the RC should not be surrounded by " ", I corrected that but something's stinky yet lol.

Comment: Just one note, I've just tested this in a simple sheet with 4 columns. It only works if the extra space is in the columns that are being tested, not in the cell where the criteria is. Because obviously if you're testing against "test ", even with wildcards "test" won't give a hit. But if you're testing against "test", then with wildcards "test " will give a hit.

Comment: I have recorded a macro, finally and this is the formula with all quotations, thank you for the hint @Sven !! https://imgur.com/RMj3cxM